# python3 redis-py how to auto parse hgetall result?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

```
import redis

config=redis.Redis(host='localhost')
dic={'name':'tom','age':20,'subjects':['eng','cn']}
config.hmset('person',dic)

print(config.hgetall('person'))
```

will get `{b'age': b'20', b'name': b'tom', b'subjects': b"['eng', 'cn']"}`.
But I want to get `dic` object back. namely:`{'name':'tom','age':20,'subjects':['eng','cn']}`, how?

Answer (score 2):

Add `decode_responses=True` to `Redis()` argument.

```
import redis

config=redis.Redis(host='localhost', decode_responses=True)
dic={'name':'tom','age':20,'subjects':['eng','cn']}
config.hmset('person',dic)

print(config.hgetall('person'))
```

Comment: its working. any idea why is character 'b' included in the response?